# TThemeServices::DrawText unresolved link error

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I'm creating a custom component (derived from TCustomCategoryPanelGroup) and performing some custom draw operations. I want to handle when Themes are enabled and draw text appropriately.

Here is a snippet of some code I have in a draw function:

```
int theBaseDrawFlags = DT_EXPANDTABS | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_VCENTER | DT_LEFT;
theBaseDrawFlags = DrawTextBiDiModeFlags( theBaseDrawFlags );

if ( TCustomCategoryPanelGroup::hsThemed == PanelGroup->HeaderStyle && ThemeServices()->ThemesEnabled )
{
    ThemeServices()->DrawText( ACanvas->Handle, ThemeServices()->GetElementDetails( tebNormalGroupHead ), m_CaptionTopLeft, m_TextRect, theBaseDrawFlags, 0 );
}
else
{
    // Draw without themes
}
```

When I attempt to build this I receive the error:

```
Unresolved external __fastcall Themes::TThemeServices::DrawTextA(HDC__ *, Themes::TThemedElementDetails&, const System::WideString, Types::TRect&, unsigned int, unsigned int)' referenced from  ....
```

As you can see it's looking for `DrawTextA`. I've looked at the Themes.hpp header and there is only a `ThemeServices::DrawText` function defined.

I'm not sure what's going on here. I thought perhaps that I was missing an import library, but all of the other ThemeServices functions that I use don't get link errors.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using C++Builder XE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have `#include`d some header (windows.h?) that contains something like this

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define DrawText DrawTextW
#else
#define DrawText DrawTextA
#endif
```

You can probably put an `#undef DrawText` in your file to work around this. (See also [Conflict with DrawText function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779185/conflict-with-drawtext-function).)

Comment: ThemeServices::DrawText() is not my code, it's Embarcadero's. I've attempted different variants of your suggestion (and the linked question) just to explore the idea. I'm not convinced this is that type of problem. It almost seems like it's a problem in the way the Themes.hpp header (which contains the ThemeServices class) is generating, and how it is different from the library that is being linked to.

Comment: But the code you posted above **is** your code, isn't it? And if above it DrawText is `#define`d to mean DrawTextA then your call `ThemeServices()->DrawText` will be translated to `ThemeServices()->DrawTextA` by the preprocessor - which would explain the compiler error you get.

Comment: @Ulrich, the error indicates that `DrawText` was defined to `DrawTextA` before `TThemeServices` was declared, not just before Scott's call. Otherwise, the error would have been about an undeclared identifier at the call site. But Scott sees a linker error, so at the time the compiler saw the call, it thought it was to a valid function, which means the declaration in the header was affected, too. Scott, after you include *windows.h*, but before you include *Themes.hpp*, use Ulrich's suggestion to undefine `DrawText`.

Comment: Yes, it is my code. I think the assumption being made here is that `ThemeServices` has exported functions named `DrawTextA` and `DrawTextW`. If this were the case, the preprocessor trick would work. If I dump the binary that has ThemeServices (vcl150.bpl), I only see `DrawText`. Whereas if you  dump something like User32.dll you see the expected `DrawTextA` and `DrawTextW`. Does this make sense or am I still not seeing something? (BTW, thanks for trying to help).

Comment: @Rob-Kennedy, if I undefine DrawText at file scope my other calls to DrawText (non-ThemeServices calls) will get messed up. I'm wondering if Embarcadero has a problem here where they should have actually created functions `DrawTextA` and `DrawTextW`, but they failed to do so? It seems like they didn't abide by the conventions on this one?

Comment: Kind of a workaround but I moved all other non-ThemeServices DrawText calls outside of this class and then did the #undef DrawText prior to the include of Themes.hpp. It now links.